# Adding bootstrap btn-group to panel-heading adds space below panel-heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a button into a panel-heading section, but I can't get it to display on the same line. I've managed to get it centered with help of some of the questions on StackOverflow where others asked about a button on the right of the header, but adding the button in seems to make the header taller.

I've got an example showing the difference [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/OPW5a9NnNH)

**Code**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getApplications()">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
       <b>Title has space below</b>
         <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">new</a>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Release Date</th>
                    <th>Orders</th>
                    <th>Downloads</th>
                    <th>Activations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
                    <td>{{app.columns.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{app.lastReleaseDt}} </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalOrders}}</td>
                    <td>TODO </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalActivations}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getApplications()">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
       <b>Title has no space</b>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Release Date</th>
                    <th>Orders</th>
                    <th>Downloads</th>
                    <th>Activations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
                    <td>{{app.columns.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{app.lastReleaseDt}} </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalOrders}}</td>
                    <td>TODO </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalActivations}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anybody have any ideas why adding a button or button group to the panel heading increases the height? Any tips on getting the height to what it was before the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using a `btn-sm` (for small-devices) if you use `btn-xs` (for extra-small devices) that space will go away due to having a smaller `padding`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getApplications()">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
       <b>Title has space below</b>
         <div class="btn-group pull-right">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">new</a>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Release Date</th>
                    <th>Orders</th>
                    <th>Downloads</th>
                    <th>Activations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
                    <td>{{app.columns.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{app.lastReleaseDt}} </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalOrders}}</td>
                    <td>TODO </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalActivations}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-init="getApplications()">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
       <b>Title has no space</b>
     </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <!-- table -->
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Last Release Date</th>
                    <th>Orders</th>
                    <th>Downloads</th>
                    <th>Activations</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="app in apps">
                    <td>{{app.columns.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{app.lastReleaseDt}} </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalOrders}}</td>
                    <td>TODO </td>
                    <td>{{app.totalActivations}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat! This has been bugging me for far too long haha looks much better now! Thanks!